# Is that correct about dimensionality reduction and clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, dimensionality-reduction, self-organizing-maps

Could you please help me to understand it because I'm not sure if I got it correctly. Let's say I have a dataset, of persons, with 100 features, various characteristics like height, weight, age, etc. I want to classify if are normal or abnormal. By abnormal I mean if a 20 years old man is 170cm and 150kg to identify it as abnormal.

Should I use Self Organising Map to reduce the dimensionality (these 100 features) and then K-means to classify them into normal and abnormal? Is that a correct approach?

And if later I'd like to find why this person has included into the abnormal class how can I find that this happened because of these two features, his weight according to his height?

Answer (score 1):

This depends a lot on your *method*.

For above data set, decision trees and random forest may work well.

They do not need dimensionality reduction; it will likely even *harm* your result.

K-Means on the other hand will *not* work on such data very well, because data *normalization* is really difficult to do right.

But you appear to be interested in *classification, not clustering* anyway.

Comment: So, can I just use K-NN? With hundreds features? And then a decision tree in order to find somehow the features which are responsible for the abnormality?

Comment: What do you mean by K-NN here? You do not combine K-NN with decision trees.

Comment: Anony-Mouse How many features can I use with K-NN without the need of any algorithm for dimensionality reduction?

Comment: Depends on your data. With textual data and cosinen thousands. With Euclidean: a dozen or two, if you carefully weighted them. Or you use an algorithm that better fits your data & problem.